# Why all completed jobs were part of Azure automation script?

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I added couple of runbook in Azure automation. Now, when I look at my azure resource group automation script, I see it includes all the completed jobs and so many other things. I feel somehing wrong here. Why all completed jobs were part of the automation script? Please check the script below.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_sku": {
        "defaultValue": null,
        "type": "SecureObject"
    },
    "automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "storageAccounts_ordersbloblogsdut_name": {
        "defaultValue": "ordersbloblogsdut",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "runbooks_PurgeLogs_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/PurgeLogs",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "runbooks_deleteItems_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/deleteItems",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "modules_Azure_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/Azure",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "modules_Azure.Storage_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/Azure.Storage",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "modules_AzureRM.Automation_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/AzureRM.Automation",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "modules_AzureRM.Compute_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/AzureRM.Compute",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "modules_AzureRM.Profile_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/AzureRM.Profile",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "modules_AzureRM.Resources_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/AzureRM.Resources",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "modules_AzureRM.Sql_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/AzureRM.Sql",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "modules_AzureRM.Storage_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/AzureRM.Storage",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "modules_Microsoft.PowerShell.Core_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "modules_Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "modules_Microsoft.PowerShell.Management_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "modules_Microsoft.PowerShell.Security_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "modules_Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "modules_Microsoft.WSMan.Management_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/Microsoft.WSMan.Management",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "modules_Orchestrator.AssetManagement.Cmdlets_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/Orchestrator.AssetManagement.Cmdlets",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "schedules_PurgeLogsSchedule_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/PurgeLogsSchedule",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "schedules_deleteItemsSchedule_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/deleteItemsSchedule",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_dddefbc6_ce31_4baf_8289_091694ff6605_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/dddefbc6-ce31-4baf-8289-091694ff6605",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_d6d7ae51_1fb2_46f1_86c8_251279e093df_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/d6d7ae51-1fb2-46f1-86c8-251279e093df",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_1d2d3f92_5524_4a91_9c47_8e236bc8d46d_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/1d2d3f92-5524-4a91-9c47-8e236bc8d46d",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_8bf70d4a_3143_4d6e_91ef_14f0d33c9235_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/8bf70d4a-3143-4d6e-91ef-14f0d33c9235",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_589caa59_46d5_44d7_8b9d_d754364f09fa_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/589caa59-46d5-44d7-8b9d-d754364f09fa",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_fa6d44b2_3c23_41a2_b14d_81a3f3b1e279_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/fa6d44b2-3c23-41a2-b14d-81a3f3b1e279",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_a7be24d1_588e_4203_a7ae_40c7799e8a63_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/a7be24d1-588e-4203-a7ae-40c7799e8a63",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_75fdb298_12d6_47d9_9ef9_769103641370_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/75fdb298-12d6-47d9-9ef9-769103641370",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_21459a62_bda8_48a1_ac77_fc77edb7277c_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/21459a62-bda8-48a1-ac77-fc77edb7277c",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_68389ebd_d78c_4540_b1e3_fc918c3d7a6f_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/68389ebd-d78c-4540-b1e3-fc918c3d7a6f",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_c9eda4f3_b727_4e1c_8232_276fc1738cac_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/c9eda4f3-b727-4e1c-8232-276fc1738cac",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_84805e33_6b65_4527_872f_94c01d4bd52f_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/84805e33-6b65-4527-872f-94c01d4bd52f",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_b8f9e3a7_b8c9_4ace_b005_cb7a8a8042f4_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/b8f9e3a7-b8c9-4ace-b005-cb7a8a8042f4",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_b415353f_da2a_40b3_88b0_5b99bf00db69_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/b415353f-da2a-40b3-88b0-5b99bf00db69",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_660b1e97_5451_471e_ad6e_f9e2b3fbdf31_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/660b1e97-5451-471e-ad6e-f9e2b3fbdf31",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_9c3f026b_e7d1_45b0_95b4_6884ea560b9d_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/9c3f026b-e7d1-45b0-95b4-6884ea560b9d",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_8d650ae4_8f7d_407f_b9c9_31e6bb902d3d_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/8d650ae4-8f7d-407f-b9c9-31e6bb902d3d",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_f37e4e76_3fff_488c_9d5c_5b6539d626e0_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/f37e4e76-3fff-488c-9d5c-5b6539d626e0",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_2e18b738_b549_45cc_ac2f_90708feeff1d_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/2e18b738-b549-45cc-ac2f-90708feeff1d",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_a754695e_3cd2_4aec_878f_8cd9a5728b95_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/a754695e-3cd2-4aec-878f-8cd9a5728b95",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_b92a4ff4_c4ca_472c_9031_e4b456f77f30_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/b92a4ff4-c4ca-472c-9031-e4b456f77f30",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_91a2d834_8c37_461d_acce_473594bd3f5d_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/91a2d834-8c37-461d-acce-473594bd3f5d",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_72014de4_d6fb_4d57_b9b9_5c8fd9cde973_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/72014de4-d6fb-4d57-b9b9-5c8fd9cde973",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_3de2322a_f04d_452c_aed6_7650e0d3eaa2_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/3de2322a-f04d-452c-aed6-7650e0d3eaa2",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_23e0e810_98fc_4e78_af4c_cdc0da2b8d77_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/23e0e810-98fc-4e78-af4c-cdc0da2b8d77",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_d2428518_fd4c_41d6_88f4_27402401b4dd_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/d2428518-fd4c-41d6-88f4-27402401b4dd",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_1d61307a_2e25_4064_87f5_e83e37d6ff26_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/1d61307a-2e25-4064-87f5-e83e37d6ff26",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_cc668047_7090_4946_a81a_63270eadaf98_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/cc668047-7090-4946-a81a-63270eadaf98",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_a11ecdbf_5b10_4fa6_add5_8541838f0ded_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/a11ecdbf-5b10-4fa6-add5-8541838f0ded",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobs_825455ac_8f5e_4611_8a30_11607b566a69_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/825455ac-8f5e-4611-8a30-11607b566a69",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobSchedules_77c19c90_ed86_4a1c_96d3_c41746833890_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/77c19c90-ed86-4a1c-96d3-c41746833890",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "jobSchedules_30987e26_6340_4ba2_9f75_42944881c9d6_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test3-Automation/30987e26-6340-4ba2-9f75-42944881c9d6",
        "type": "String"
    }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/65b7453f-0c39-4f3f-a113-c0f107f431c4/resourcegroups/Test-Data/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/test3-Automation'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts",
        "name": "[parameters('automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
        "location": "southcentralus",
        "properties": {
            "sku": "[parameters('automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_sku')]"
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": []
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/65b7453f-0c39-4f3f-a113-c0f107f431c4/resourceGroups/Test-data/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/ordersbloblogsdut'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "sku": {
            "name": "Standard_LRS",
            "tier": "Standard"
        },
        "kind": "BlobStorage",
        "name": "[parameters('storageAccounts_ordersbloblogsdut_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-01-01",
        "location": "westus",
        "tags": {},
        "properties": {
            "accessTier": "Cool"
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": []
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/65b7453f-0c39-4f3f-a113-c0f107f431c4/resourcegroups/Test-Data/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/test3-Automation/runbooks/PurgeLogs'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/runbooks",
        "name": "[parameters('runbooks_PurgeLogs_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
        "location": "southcentralus",
        "properties": {
            "runbookType": "Script",
            "logVerbose": false,
            "logProgress": false
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/65b7453f-0c39-4f3f-a113-c0f107f431c4/resourcegroups/Test-Data/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/test3-Automation/runbooks/deleteItems'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/runbooks",
        "name": "[parameters('runbooks_deleteItems_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
        "location": "southcentralus",
        "properties": {
            "runbookType": "Script",
            "logVerbose": false,
            "logProgress": false
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/65b7453f-0c39-4f3f-a113-c0f107f431c4/resourcegroups/Test-Data/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/test3-Automation/modules/Azure'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules",
        "name": "[parameters('modules_Azure_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
        "properties": {
            "isGlobal": true,
            "version": null,
            "sizeInBytes": 0
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/65b7453f-0c39-4f3f-a113-c0f107f431c4/resourcegroups/Test-Data/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/test3-Automation/modules/Azure.Storage'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules",
        "name": "[parameters('modules_Azure.Storage_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
        "properties": {
            "isGlobal": true,
            "version": null,
            "sizeInBytes": 0
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/65b7453f-0c39-4f3f-a113-c0f107f431c4/resourcegroups/Test-Data/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/test3-Automation/modules/AzureRM.Automation'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules",
        "name": "[parameters('modules_AzureRM.Automation_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
        "properties": {
            "isGlobal": true,
            "version": null,
            "sizeInBytes": 0
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/65b7453f-0c39-4f3f-a113-c0f107f431c4/resourcegroups/Test-Data/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/test3-Automation/modules/AzureRM.Compute'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules",
        "name": "[parameters('modules_AzureRM.Compute_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
        "properties": {
            "isGlobal": true,
            "version": null,
            "sizeInBytes": 0
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/65b7453f-0c39-4f3f-a113-c0f107f431c4/resourcegroups/Test-Data/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/test3-Automation/modules/AzureRM.Profile'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules",
        "name": "[parameters('modules_AzureRM.Profile_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
        "properties": {
            "isGlobal": true,
            "version": null,
            "sizeInBytes": 0
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/65b7453f-0c39-4f3f-a113-c0f107f431c4/resourcegroups/Test-Data/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/test3-Automation/modules/AzureRM.Resources'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules",
        "name": "[parameters('modules_AzureRM.Resources_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
        "properties": {
            "isGlobal": true,
            "version": null,
            "sizeInBytes": 0
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/65b7453f-0c39-4f3f-a113-c0f107f431c4/resourcegroups/Test-Data/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/test3-Automation/modules/AzureRM.Sql'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules",
        "name": "[parameters('modules_AzureRM.Sql_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
        "properties": {
            "isGlobal": true,
            "version": null,
            "sizeInBytes": 0
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/65b7453f-0c39-4f3f-a113-c0f107f431c4/resourcegroups/Test-Data/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/test3-Automation/modules/AzureRM.Storage'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules",
        "name": "[parameters('modules_AzureRM.Storage_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
        "properties": {
            "isGlobal": true,
            "version": null,
            "sizeInBytes": 0
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/65b7453f-0c39-4f3f-a113-c0f107f431c4/resourcegroups/Test-Data/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/test3-Automation/modules/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules",
        "name": "[parameters('modules_Microsoft.PowerShell.Core_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
        "properties": {
            "isGlobal": true,
            "version": null,
            "sizeInBytes": 0
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/65b7453f-0c39-4f3f-a113-c0f107f431c4/resourcegroups/Test-Data/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/test3-Automation/modules/Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules",
        "name": "[parameters('modules_Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
        "properties": {
            "isGlobal": true,
            "version": null,
            "sizeInBytes": 0
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/65b7453f-0c39-4f3f-a113-c0f107f431c4/resourcegroups/Test-Data/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/test3-Automation/modules/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules",
        "name": "[parameters('modules_Microsoft.PowerShell.Management_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
        "properties": {
            "isGlobal": true,
            "version": null,
            "sizeInBytes": 0
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/65b7453f-0c39-4f3f-a113-c0f107f431c4/resourcegroups/Test-Data/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/test3-Automation/modules/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules",
        "name": "[parameters('modules_Microsoft.PowerShell.Security_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
        "properties": {
            "isGlobal": true,
            "version": null,
            "sizeInBytes": 0
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/65b7453f-0c39-4f3f-a113-c0f107f431c4/resourcegroups/Test-Data/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/test3-Automation/modules/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules",
        "name": "[parameters('modules_Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
        "properties": {
            "isGlobal": true,
            "version": null,
            "sizeInBytes": 0
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/65b7453f-0c39-4f3f-a113-c0f107f431c4/resourcegroups/Test-Data/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/test3-Automation/modules/Microsoft.WSMan.Management'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules",
        "name": "[parameters('modules_Microsoft.WSMan.Management_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
        "properties": {
            "isGlobal": true,
            "version": null,
            "sizeInBytes": 0
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/65b7453f-0c39-4f3f-a113-c0f107f431c4/resourcegroups/Test-Data/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/test3-Automation/modules/Orchestrator.AssetManagement.Cmdlets'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules",
        "name": "[parameters('modules_Orchestrator.AssetManagement.Cmdlets_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
        "properties": {
            "isGlobal": true,
            "version": null,
            "sizeInBytes": 0
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccounts_Test2_Automation_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {//truncating the rest
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, as I observe the exact same behavior on several accounts I believe this is perfectly fine. Yet I have no explanation to this. The funniesT thing is - if you would want to migrate Azure Automation to another resource group all of those will migrate over also (I've tested it recently, just for fun).
**Bottom line:** this is expected.

Answer (score 0):

The above template has parameters declared for the jobs, but those parameters are never used anywhere, nor does the template say to actually deploy any jobs. Assuming the template above is the full template, you can either remove those job parameters or ignore them completely.

This template doesn't do this, but the reason you might want Automation jobs in an ARM template is to declare that those jobs should be run as part of the ARM template deployment, either once or every deployment. Since the job(s) would be in the template, you could even use the `dependsOn` property of a resource to say that some other resource should only be deployed after the job(s) completes.

If you hard code the name of a job, it will only be run as part of deployment if there is not already a job with that name in the Automation account the job is under. If you make the job name a parameter and pass a different, unused job name in each deployment, the job will be run as part of every deployment.

Automation jobs essentially allow you to add imperative steps, and tasks that might not be related to Azure, to your ARM template deployments, since an Automation job is just arbitrary PowerShell code.